# Find nlargest(2) with corresponding value after groupby

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a Dataframe as below:

```
Datetime             Volume       Price
2020-08-05 09:15:00  1033         504
2020-08-05 09:15:00  1960         516
2020-08-05 09:15:00  1724         520
2020-08-05 09:15:00  1870         540
2020-08-05 09:20:00  1024         576
2020-08-05 09:20:00  1960         548
2020-08-05 09:20:00  1426         526
2020-08-05 09:20:00  1968         518
2020-08-05 09:30:00  1458         511
2020-08-05 09:30:00  1333         534
2020-08-05 09:30:00  1322         555
2020-08-05 09:30:00  1425         567
2020-08-05 09:30:00  1245         598
```

I want to find top two max Volume with corresponding Price after groupby on Datetime column.

Result Dataframe as below:

```
Datetime             Volume       Price
2020-08-05 09:15:00  1960         516
2020-08-05 09:15:00  1870         540
2020-08-05 09:20:00  1960         548
2020-08-05 09:20:00  1968         518
2020-08-05 09:30:00  1858         511
2020-08-05 09:30:00  1925         567
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you mentioned `nlargest`

```
out = df.groupby('Datetime',as_index=False).apply(lambda x : x.nlargest(2, columns=['Volume']))
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `sort_values` before `groupby`:

```
print (df.sort_values("Volume", ascending=False)
         .groupby("Datetime").head(2).sort_index())

               Datetime  Volume  Price
1   2020-08-05 09:15:00    1960    516
3   2020-08-05 09:15:00    1870    540
5   2020-08-05 09:20:00    1960    548
7   2020-08-05 09:20:00    1968    518
8   2020-08-05 09:30:00    1458    511
11  2020-08-05 09:30:00    1425    567
```

Answer (score 4):

using `groupby.rank` + `boolean indexing`:

```
df[df.groupby("Datetime")['Volume'].rank(ascending=False).le(2)]
```

---

```
              Datetime  Volume  Price
1   2020-08-05 09:15:00    1960    516
3   2020-08-05 09:15:00    1870    540
5   2020-08-05 09:20:00    1960    548
7   2020-08-05 09:20:00    1968    518
8   2020-08-05 09:30:00    1458    511
11  2020-08-05 09:30:00    1425    567
```